# How to convert my custom json to swagger 2.0 json

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm new to swagger documentation. We have an existing project developed in progress language for RESTFul Web Services. The different resource based urls consumes and produces in application/json format. The input and output json formats for one of our resource url is given below:

## Request:

```
{
    "request": {
      "companyNumber": 5000,
      "operatorInit": "sys",
      "operatorPassword": "",
      "customerNumber": 101,
      "shipTo": "",
      "warehouse": "01",
      "productCode": "2-001",
      "crossReferenceFlag": false,
      "retrieveFlag": false,
      "tInbinlocation": {
        "t-inbinlocation": [
          {
            "binloc": "",
            "icswbinloc1fl": false,
            "icswbinloc2fl": false,
            "addrecordfl": false,
            "deleterecordfl": false,
            "charuser": "",
            "user1": "",
            "user2": "",
            "user3": "",
            "user4": "",
            "user5": "",
            "user6": 0,
            "user7": 0,
            "user8": null,
            "user9": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "tInfieldvalue": {
        "t-infieldvalue": [
          {
            "level": "",
            "lineno": 0,
            "seqno": 0,
            "fieldname": "",
            "fieldvalue": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

## Response:

```
{
  "response": {
    "cErrorMessage": "",
    "crossReferenceProduct": "2-001",
    "crossReferenceType": "",
    "tOutbinlocation": {
      "t-outbinlocation": []
    },
    "tOutfieldvalue": {
      "t-outfieldvalue": []
    }
  }
}
```

How to convert above request and response json formats into swagger 2.0 json format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [api-spec-converter](https://github.com/lucybot/api-spec-converter).

 this tool supports converting API descriptions between popular formats.

```
  Supported formats:
    * swagger_1
    * swagger_2
    * api_blueprint
    * io_docs
    * google
    * raml
    * wadl
```

Comment: I have installed api-spec-converter. I'm trying to call api-spec-converter http://<HOST>:<PORT>/sxapi/rest/sxapirestservice/sxapiicbinlocationmnt --from=api_blueprint --to=swagger_2 swagger.json. But it gives method not supported error. We support only POST requests. How to do it using api-spec-converter?

Comment: It doesn't convert JSON to Swagger as per  the user's request.